# I want to display the name of the values in django anotate

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to build a mini bank like app where I can do deposits and withdrawals. In one of the templates, I want to sum all the deposits and withdrawals in the model which has the same currency name in common, so I use annotate which works fine.
But I couldn't display the name of the currency in the template. Instead, it is displaying 1,2,3 instead of Pound, Dollar, Euro.

Here is the relevant part of my model:

```
class Banks(models.Model):
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, blank=True, null=True)
    total_deposits = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_withdrawals = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is the view:

```
result = Banks.objects.values('currency'
        ).order_by('currency'
        ).annotate(total_withdrawals=Sum('total_withdrawals')
        ).annotate(total_deposits=Sum('total_deposits')
        )

context = {
        "result": result,
        }
```

Here is the template:

```
<table class='table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class='aligncenter'>#</th>
              <th class='aligncenter'>CURRENCY</th>
              <th class='aligncenter'>TOTAL DEPOSITS</th>
              <th class='aligncenter'>TOTAL WITHDRAWALS</th>
              <th class='aligncenter'>BALANCE</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        {% for instance in result %}
            <tr>
              <td class='aligncenter'>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
              <td class='aligncenter'>{{instance.currency}}</td>
              <td class='aligncenter'>{{instance.total_deposits}}</td>
              <td class='aligncenter'>{{instance.total_withdrawals}}</td>
              <td class='aligncenter'>{{instance.total_deposits|sub:instance.total_withdrawals}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

here is the template output:
[image]

**I want to see the currency name under the currency column. Not 1, 2 and 3**

Comment: Can you share the `Currency` model?

Comment: `{{instance.currency}}` return currency ID (I guess you override `__str__` method in `Currency` model to do so). Instead or change `__str__` method of that model to return whatever field you have for currency name there or do the same in template by referring that field `{{instance.currency.currency_name_field}}`

Comment: @Charnel: this is the case because of the `.values(..)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, since it's a FK it will return an integer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: here is the `Currency` model:

`class Currency(models.Model):`
 `name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True)`
 `symbol = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True)`
 `def __unicode__(self):`
  `return self.symbol`

Answer (score 1):

You should add the name of the currency to your values, you can do this with:

```
from django.db.models import F

result = Banks.objects.values(
    'currency',
    currency_name=F('currency__name')
).order_by('currency', 'currency_name').annotate(
    total_withdrawals=Sum('total_withdrawals'),
    total_deposits=Sum('total_deposits')
)
```

(assuming a `Currency` has a `name` field, if it has a different field, you can replace this with `F('currency__fieldname')` for that *`fieldname`*).

Then you can render this with:

```
<td class='aligncenter'>{{ instance.currency_name }}</td>
```

That being said, since you here group per currency, it makes more sense to simply *annotate* your currencies, like:

```
result = Currency.objects.annotate(
    total_withdrawals=Sum('banks__total_withdrawals'),
    total_deposits=Sum('banks__total_deposits')
)
```

Then you can render the `instance, which will call the`str(..)`on the`Currency` object, for example with:

```
<td class='aligncenter'>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
<td class='aligncenter'>{{ instance }}</td>
<td class='aligncenter'>{{ instance.total_deposits }}</td>
<td class='aligncenter'>{{ instance.total_withdrawals }}</td>
<td class='aligncenter'>{{ instance.total_deposits|sub:instance.total_withdrawals }}</td>
```

Comment: I guess this is what am looking for. But i got this error: 
TypeError at /uimsapp/client_list/
values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'currency_name'

Comment: @simplyvic: did you use double underscores (`__`), does the `Currency` model has a field `name`?

Comment: @willen Van Onsem: yes i used double underscores and the currency model does have a field name. The error is complaining of the first currency_name, not the one in bracket.

Comment: @simplyvic: what version of Django do you use? 1.10 and older indeed do not support that (although these are outdated).

Comment: Oh, I am using Django 1.8. I need to upgrade then. I will get back to update you after upgrading.